# trying to delete a mysql database entry with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I use ajax to show the database thusly:

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {
                echo "<div class=\"text\"><span>";
                echo $row2['name'];
                echo "</span><br/>";
            }
            echo "<b>";
            echo $row['subject'];
            echo "</b>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['description'];
            echo "<div class=\"date\">" . date("D, M y g:ia",strtotime($row['timestamp'])) . "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<div class=\"clear\"></div>";
            echo "<a href=\"?delete=";
            echo $row['id'];
            echo "\" class=\"delete\">Delete</a>";
            echo "</div>";
```

but I'm having trouble deleting it.

I've tried putting this in the head, but it doesn't actually delete it...:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'delete.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''), beforeSend: function() {
        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
      }, success: function() {
            parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                parent.remove();
            });
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Any advice where to start?

Comment: Have you separately tested `delete.php` and know that it works when the correct query string is present? Have you used your browser's developer tools to see if a request is being made when the link is clicked, and whether that request is to the URL you expect?

Comment: You seem to be filling in the `delete=` parameter of your URL using an ID (`parent-#`) of some element that doesn't exist in the code you've shared for this webpage.

Comment: can you post the contents of `delete.php` to check where the problem occurs?

Comment: $id = $_POST['id'];
 $sql = "DELETE FROM ajax_demo WHERE id = $id";
 mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 echo "Message Deleted.";

Comment: I'm getting a "$ is not defined" for this line:  $('a.delete').click(function(e) {

Comment: for that error, I don`t know about it ... but I can see a problem in your query. The table name has got a space and that sometimes makes a problem, so try making it with an underscore "_". And also try running the query as it is on the MySQL directly and see if a problem is detected.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error you mentioned, I assume, you need to include JQuery before the javascript in the html head...